# How can I redirect based on geographical location with W3 Total Cache enabled?

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation, w3-total-cache

Using WordPress Multi-site install and W3 Total Cache with hosting on Amazon EC2, I want to create a redirect for one set of pages based on the geolocation of user.

To be more clear: I have one US content page, and one non-US content page.  If someone in the US visits the non-US page they should be redirected, and vise versa, if someone from Canada visits the US page they should be redirected.

I am open to using a service in my hosting environment, another plug in for WordPress (as long as it doesn't affect the W3 Total Cache) or something that requires a coded solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@andrew If you use a structure like:

domain.com/us/page 
domain.com/global/page

these are then separate pages and will be cached separately.

Make sure that W3 isn't caching your geotargeting plugin's redirect script as it often causes problems (turn minification of js off to test).

You can also exclude pages from being cached by adding it to the exclude list in W3's admin area.

Comment: A year later, haha, but this ended up being what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider something like this.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geographical-redirect/

or

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/source-redirect-site/

or

http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-geoip-country-redirect/3589163

Or you can make your own using:

http://www.maxmind.com/en/country

Comment: The comment is not very useful since all of those plugins will not work with caching enabled - and this is what the OP asked about (he uses W3 Total Cache as a caching plugin).